# Running spark job on yarn using remote SparkContext: Yarn application has already ended

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to launch a program that creates `SparkContext` on yarn. Here is my simple program:

```
object Entry extends App {
  System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true")

  val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("test-connection")
    .setMaster("yarn-client")

  val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConfig)

  val numbersRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

  println {
    s"result is ${numbersRDD.reduce(_ + _)}"
  }
}
```

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkV      = "1.6.0"

  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-yarn" % sparkV,
  )
}
```

I'm using google cloud dataproc running this program inside the master node via `sbt run`

These are logs:

```
16/03/09 08:38:31 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1457497836188_0013 to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/03/09 08:38:32 INFO Client: Application report for application_1457497836188_0013 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/09 08:38:32 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1457512711191
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://recommendation-cluster-m:8088/proxy/application_1457497836188_0013/
     user: ibosz
16/03/09 08:38:33 INFO Client: Application report for application_1457497836188_0013 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/09 08:38:34 INFO Client: Application report for application_1457497836188_0013 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/09 08:38:35 INFO Client: Application report for application_1457497836188_0013 (state: FAILED)
16/03/09 08:38:35 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1457497836188_0013 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1457497836188_0013_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://recommendation-cluster-m:8088/cluster/app/application_1457497836188_0013Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ibosz/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-yarn_2.10/jars/spark-yarn_2.10-1.6.0.jar does not exist
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1457512711191
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://recommendation-cluster-m:8088/cluster/app/application_1457497836188_0013
     user: ibosz
16/03/09 08:38:35 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:530)
    at Entry$delayedInit$body.apply(Entry.scala:13)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at Entry$.main(Entry.scala:6)
    at Entry.main(Entry.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:67)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:61)
    at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:51)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:85)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

it says

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ibosz/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-yarn_2.10/jars/spark-yarn_2.10-1.6.0.jar does not exist
```

but it does exist. And having no problem running `spark-shell --master yarn-client`. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's probably a way to force `sbt run` to correctly do a real `yarn-client` mode Spark submission, you probably just want to do this instead:

```
sbt package
spark-submit target/scala-2.10/*SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Essentially, the error you're encountering is that when the SparkContext gets created, it asks for a remote YARN container to hold the AppMaster process, which will reside on one of your worker nodes. It's passing through aspects of your master's local environment, which includes your sbt-specific copy of the Spark assembly that was used in the build (under the `~/.ivy2/cache/` directory). The workers' environments won't match the environment in which you're running `sbt run`, which is why it fails.

Note that the `spark-submit` command is itself just a bash script whose whole purpose is to run the jarfile with all the right environment-variable and classpath configurations, so anything that gets `sbt run` to work will essentially duplicate the logic of the `spark-submit` script, and probably do it in a non-portable way.

The plus side of all this is that using `spark-submit foo.jar` will make your invocation nice and portable; once you want to productionize your job for example, you can use Dataproc's job-submission APIs on that same jarfile just like you'd use spark-submit: `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --jar foo.jar <your_job_args>`, and you can even submit those Spark jarfiles through Dataproc's web GUI just by uploading your jarfile to GCS first and then specifying the `gs://` path to your jarfile for the job.

Similarly, if you have a local spark setup just by untarring a standard Spark binary distro, you can still use `spark-submit` even if you don't have `sbt` installed on that local spark setup.